# Document workflow

Tags: osx, pdf, document-converter, markdown, plain-text

I'm looking for a solution (consisting of one or more tools) which allows me to implement a personal document *workflow* to deliver documents of a professional nature with a minimal of repetitive work (e.g. styling).

The idea behind it is that I often have to write documents where the content differs, but the styling is always limited to a handful of layouts. Currently, these documents are written in Microsoft Word, but I find that I spend too much time fiddling with the layout and that it is distracting me from what matters, i.e. the content.

As a test, I wrote one document in plain text first (well, Markdown actually) and found that I was able to focus much better on the writing itself. The penalty came afterwards when having to piece everything back into Word.

These are the requirements:

- Be able to define **templates**. These templates should contain style definitions (headers, colours, logo, …).
- Write content using **plain text** with minimal markup for styling. Ideally, this would be something like Markdown or reStructuredText.
- Generate table of contents, support for headers and footers, …
- Export to **PDF** is crucial.
- Run on **OS X**.
- A **command-line** interface.

Nice to have:

- Templates which support the use **metadata** (defined separately) to automatically create a distribution list, version overview … .
- Export to **different file types** (e.g. doc(x), HTML, …).

Remarks:

- A solution that would allow **HTML + CSS** would probably work too,  as I can convert Markdown, RST, ... to HTML (using an intermediate conversion engine).
- I would prefer **a tool instead of a pure API library**, though the latter is welcome as an addition and to implement further customisation. In that case, the API has to support **Python 3**.

What I've evaluated so far:

- [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org): Uses Latex to export to PDF. While in theory I could define Latex templates, the learning curve of Latex for what I needed it was prohibitively steep. The conversion of MD tables to PDF was also rather lacking. From what I've gathered, using reStructuredText could be a solution for the table issue.
- [Prince](http://www.princexml.com): A commercial solution. This was a fairly close match to my requirements, however the lack of clear documentation (both official documentation and information found in the forum) was a big let down.
- [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf): HTML/CSS to PDF converter based on Python. This falls somewhere between a pure API and a tool you can use out of the box. It's based on the well known ReportLab PDF generation engine. The problem with xhtml2pdf is that Python 3 support is still largely broken in the current version (0.0.6).

### Update:

In the end, I've settled for the following combination:

- [Python-Markdown](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/): converts the Markdown source document to HTML
- [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org): provides the necessary template features
- [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation): metadata is entered in a separate YAML file and read with PyYAML
- [Weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org): performs the final conversion of HTML to PDF

While they're different tools/libraries, I was able to combine them rather easily using Python, allowing me to create a PDF document formatted using CSS documents.

However, I'm still selecting No-nonsense's suggestion Docxpresso as the "correct" answer, as it has one important advantage: Docxpresso generates ODF files, which still allows you to make minor modifications before the conversion to the final PDF file.

Comment: Would HTML for the content and CSS for the styles be an acceptable approach? If so, please take a look at the chapter about iText and XML Worker in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) written by a fellow Belgian.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to have a closer look at the styling capabilities of OpenOffice. For really serious stuff, using a virtual Windows machine and Framemaker would be my preferred choice.

Comment: Please make the whole "Update" paragraph into an answer. Thanks!